# Getting a value out of a matrix outside of the loop it was created in

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to write an if statement but i need to get a value out of the "matrix" matrix/array. I can not get VBA to get h to equal the value in slot 1,1 in "matrix". I have already printed the matrix to make sure it is saving the values correctly and it is. How to i get the value in the matrix outside of the loop is was created in?

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim numberofcases As Single, r As Integer, i As Single, j As Integer, c As 
Single
Dim matrix() As String, max As Single
Dim loadmatrix() As String, loadtypes As Single, numbertypes As Single
Dim STAADloadmatrix() As String, countrow As Single, countcolumn As Single
Dim h as single

max = ((Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row))
loadtypes = ((Cells(Rows.count, "L").End(xlUp).Row))


j = 1
c = 5
i = 1
ReDim matrix(i, j)
For r = 2 To max
    ReDim matrix(i, j)
    j = 1
    If Cells(r, c) = "" Then
    ElseIf Cells(r, c) > 0 Then
    matrix(i, j) = Cells(r, c)
    j = 2
    ReDim matrix(i, j)
    matrix(i, j) = Cells(r, (c - 2))
    i = i + 1
    End If
Next r

h = matrix(1,1)

End sub
```

Comment: `ReDim` without "preserve" does erase all array contents. http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/dynamic-array.html

Answer (score 0):

I think everything will work just fine if you delete unnecessary

> Redim matrix(i, j)

inside the loop:

```
    For r = 2 To max
    j = 1 If Cells(r, c) = "" Then
    ElseIf Cells(r, c) > 0 Then
    matrix(i, j) = Cells(r, c)
    j = 2
    matrix(i, j) = Cells(r, (c - 2))
    i = i + 1
    End If
    Next r
```